# How do I change emacs's language?

Tags: emacs

I'm Spanish and I was trying the Emacs tutorial and then I realized that something doesn't make sense unless you read it in English. For example, the cursor movement:

[image]

If it were in English it would make more sense because instead of 'Atras' it would be 'Back' or 'Backwards' and then I could also understand the reason behind the choice of the 'b' character for that action. Same as 'f' for 'front', 'n' for 'next' and 'p' for 'previous'. I know that I can check out this tutorial from internet but I would like to have it in English in my own Emacs. Do any of you know how to install or change it in English?

Comment: Have you considered using "Help => Emacs Tutorial (choose language)" from the menu?

Comment: @Stefan Post it as an answer. I would like to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: The proper fix I suppose would be for the help text to explain these choices in the translation, if only perhaps with a small parenthetical to point out the English words which motivated these choices.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Emacs and wanted to read the tutorial in a specific language.  I was able to open the tutorial explicitly in English by doing this:

1. Type `emacs` in my terminal and hit ENTER to launch emacs.
2. Use **M-`** command to activate the menubar.
3. Type `h` which completes to *Help*.
4. Type `E` which completes to *Emacs Tutorial (choose language)...*.
5. Type `English` and hit ENTER to open the tutorial in English.

Have a wonderful time with Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Press `C-u C-h t`, and select the tutorial language you prefer.